# White space to the right hand side of the footer

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, whitespace, footer

Good evening all,

I hope you are well?

I was wondering if you could advise me please as to why there is a strange white space to the right hand side of my footer on the index / home page?

https://andrewh1188.github.io/go-tennis-ms1/

Many thanks for your help in advance.

All the best

Andrew

Comment: Please share a small re-producible example of your problem in code so we can help you.

Comment: Thank you @Austin that has worked. Many thanks again for your help : ) Have a great day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `margin-left: -15px;` and `margin-right: -15px;` from your `.row` css class.

Comment: Thank You Austin, This helped solve the issue I was having. Have a great day and thank you for your help : )

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding-left: 0px; and padding-right: 0px; from your .container-fluid css class.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jf3eK.png)